# How to open a child of GameObject in inspector from code (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

E.g. I have Prefab MyPrefab, it has two childs (child_1, child_2).

`AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(child_1);` opens MyPrefab in inspector instead of child_1.

Comment: I also interested in opening the concrete component/field of child_1 in inspector from code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna assume that you have a prefab and inside that prefab you have an another prefab that you wish to open using C#.

You can do that by using the [`PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource.html) method on the child prefab that you wish to open and then calling [`AssetDatabase.OpenAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.OpenAsset.html) method on the result that is returned.

## Example

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject prefab = null;

    [SerializeField]
    private string childPrefabName = string.Empty;

    private void Run()
    {
        var child = prefab.transform.Find(childPrefabName);
        var childPrefab = PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(child);

        AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(childPrefab);

    }

    [CustomEditor(typeof(TestScript))]
    public class TestScriptEditor: Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Run"))
            {
                var script = target as TestScript;
                script.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```